# What is the point in using 'UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am not sure what is the use of using `UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound` when the server can play notification sound whether or not if you register UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound. Can someone please help me understand the use of this and all the other notification types you can register.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the use of Notification Types..

Have you referred below Apple Document for other clarifications...[UIApplicationClass Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW52)

```
    UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

        if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) 
        {
            // Do what ever you need to here when notifications are disabled
        } else if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge) 
        {
            // Badge only
        } else if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) 
        {
            // Alert only
        } else if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound) 
        {
            // Sound only
        } else if (notificationTypes == (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)) 
        {
            // Badge & Alert
        } else if (notificationTypes == (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)) 

            // Badge & Sound        
        } else if (notificationTypes == (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)) 
        {
            // Alert & Sound
        } else if (notificationTypes == (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)) 
       {
            // Badge, Alert & Sound     
        }
```

if You did not include UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound as below then Sound will not play even though the payload contains sound..

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
    (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Hope it useful to you...!

Comment: My question is why use `UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound` when your notification plays sound anyways if your server has sound in it's payload.

Comment: Even the payload is having sound to play..Without Registering UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound it will not play any sound when push notifications comes...Check my modified answer..

Comment: Not for me, I only have this [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |  UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)]; and yet I can here the default sound notification from the server.